# Find all combination of values in inner-dict

Tags: python

Suppose I have a dictionary like -

```
{'a': {'w': [True, False, True],
       'x': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]],
       'y': [1, 5, 7],
       'z': True},
 'b': {'x': [1, 4, 5], 
       'y': 3}}
```

I want to find a combination of all possible inner dictionary values for each upper dictionary key.

For eg. for `a`, the possible combinations are -

```
[True, [1, 2, 3], 1, True]
[True, [1, 2, 3], 5, True] 
[True, [1, 2, 3], 7, True] 
[True, [4, 5], 1, True] 
[True, [4, 5], 5, True] 
[True, [4, 5], 7, True] 
[False, [1, 2, 3], 1, True] 
[False, [1, 2, 3], 5, True] 
[False, [1, 2, 3], 7, True] 
[False, [4, 5], 1, True] 
[False, [4, 5], 5, True] 
[False, [4, 5], 7, True]
```

(Note how the lists in lists are handled)

And for `b`,

```
[1, 3]
[4, 3]
[5, 3]
```

Since we don't know the number of keys in a and b while writing the source code, it is not possible to hardcode this via for loops.

How could I achieve this?

(This is a simplification of a much larger problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With creative use of `zip` and `itertools.product`.

I went a little further and chose to return dicts instead of just value lists, but you could just do `yield combo` instead of `yield dict(zip(keys, combo)` if you really need value lists.

Your original desired output also elides duplicates from each value list (`[True, False, True]` is interpreted as `[True, False]`); that's easy enough to add as something like `values = [set(v) for v in values]` if you need that.

```
import itertools


def combos(x: dict):
    keys, values = zip(*x.items())
    # Ensure all options are iterable
    values = [[v] if not isinstance(v, (list, tuple)) else v for v in values]
    for combo in itertools.product(*values):
        yield dict(zip(keys, combo))


for obj in (
    {"w": [True, False, True], "x": [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]], "y": [1, 5, 7], "z": True},
    {"x": [1, 4, 5], "y": 3},
):
    for combo in combos(obj):
        print(combo)
    print("====")
```

prints out

```
{'w': True, 'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': 1, 'z': True}
{'w': True, 'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': 5, 'z': True}
{'w': True, 'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': 7, 'z': True}
{'w': True, 'x': [4, 5], 'y': 1, 'z': True}
{'w': True, 'x': [4, 5], 'y': 5, 'z': True}
{'w': True, 'x': [4, 5], 'y': 7, 'z': True}
{'w': False, 'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': 1, 'z': True}
{'w': False, 'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': 5, 'z': True}
{'w': False, 'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': 7, 'z': True}
{'w': False, 'x': [4, 5], 'y': 1, 'z': True}
{'w': False, 'x': [4, 5], 'y': 5, 'z': True}
{'w': False, 'x': [4, 5], 'y': 7, 'z': True}
{'w': True, 'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': 1, 'z': True}
{'w': True, 'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': 5, 'z': True}
{'w': True, 'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': 7, 'z': True}
{'w': True, 'x': [4, 5], 'y': 1, 'z': True}
{'w': True, 'x': [4, 5], 'y': 5, 'z': True}
{'w': True, 'x': [4, 5], 'y': 7, 'z': True}
====
{'x': 1, 'y': 3}
{'x': 4, 'y': 3}
{'x': 5, 'y': 3}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `product` and `Iterable` from the `collections` module.

```
from itertools import product
from collections.abc import Iterable

d = {'a': {'w': [True, False, True],
       'x': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]],
       'y': [1, 5, 7],
       'z': True},
 'b': {'x': [1, 4, 5], 
       'y': 3}}

out = [
    list(product(
        *[v if isinstance(v, Iterable) else [v] for v in d[k].values()]
    )) 
    for k in d
]

out
# returns:
[[(True, [1, 2, 3], 1, True),
  (True, [1, 2, 3], 5, True),
  (True, [1, 2, 3], 7, True),
  (True, [4, 5], 1, True),
  (True, [4, 5], 5, True),
  (True, [4, 5], 7, True),
  (False, [1, 2, 3], 1, True),
  (False, [1, 2, 3], 5, True),
  (False, [1, 2, 3], 7, True),
  (False, [4, 5], 1, True),
  (False, [4, 5], 5, True),
  (False, [4, 5], 7, True),
  (True, [1, 2, 3], 1, True),
  (True, [1, 2, 3], 5, True),
  (True, [1, 2, 3], 7, True),
  (True, [4, 5], 1, True),
  (True, [4, 5], 5, True),
  (True, [4, 5], 7, True)],
 [(1, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3)]]
```